# Enable TLS 1.2 only in apache-tomcat-9 and Java 8

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, java-8, tomcat9

I have deployed my web application in Apache Tomcat 9.x.x and I have two options for Java

- Openjdk version 1.8.x
- Oracle Java 1.8.x

I need to allow TLS 1.2 only.

Please help guide me to achieve this.

I have tried to follow the following links(Not sure if they are outdated).

But https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=<< my public IP >> says : TLS 1.1 & TLS 1.0 are still enabled.

[how to enable TLS v1.2 in Apache tomcat 8 , I am using Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103279/how-to-enable-tls-v1-2-in-apache-tomcat-8-i-am-using-java-8)

[How do I disable SSLv3 in tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401465/how-do-i-disable-sslv3-in-tomcat)

[Does Tomcat support TLS v1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749339/does-tomcat-support-tls-v1-2)  (The two steps mentioned by **oraclesoon** doesn't seem to work)

[How do I disable SSLv3 support in Apache Tomcat?](https://serverfault.com/questions/637649/how-do-i-disable-sslv3-support-in-apache-tomcat)

Also [HOW TO -- Disable weak ciphers in Tomcat 7 & 8](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/659/17/how-to----disable-weak-ciphers-in-tomcat-7--8) says **sslProtocol** is no longer used in java 8

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure the Connector in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml file. An example of an APR configuration is:

```
<!-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
<Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           SSLCertificateFile="/usr/local/ssl/server.crt"
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="/usr/local/ssl/server.pem"
           SSLVerifyClient="optional" SSLProtocol="TLSv1.2"/>
```

Please refer this [configuration guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) and try that out.

Comment: Using https://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/,  I have configured   <<<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="SSL" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
        keystoreFile="/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.10/keystoreTomcat"
        keystorePass="ks1234"  allowTrace="true" >>

Comment: Anyway I don't see a property called `sslEnabledProtocols` in the documentation.

Comment: As mentioned in the Question,   https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=<< my public IP >> says : TLS 1.1 & TLS 1.0 are still enabled.

Comment: Change your `SSLProtocol="TLSv1.2"` and check that again.

Comment: I shall do that. But there is already one sslProtocol="SSL" as found in many documents. Are these  attributes of connector case sensitive. Shall I remove  sslProtocol   ?

Comment: yeah there may be subtle changes between different versions. Better stick to the exact documentation of that version IMHO.

Comment: The difference is due the Connector protocol (See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Edit_the_Tomcat_Configuration_File). The following configuration did not help  <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false"   sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"
        keystoreFile="/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.10/keystoreTomcat"
        keystorePass="ks1234"  allowTrace="true" />

Comment: I shall try with your Http11AprProtocol. But do I need to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343681/how-to-convert-trust-certificate-from-jks-to-pem  ?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Did you get it to work with the Http11NioProtocol? I am trying to figure out an implementation for TLSv1.3

Answer (score 2):

I use tomcat 9.0.14 and JSSE. it works fine. (using TLSV1.1 and TLSV1.2)

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
    <SSLHostConfig protocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2">     
    <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/keystore.jks" 
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

See: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check on a request by request basis to ensure that someone hasn't misconfigured your server, you can add a *ContainerRequestFilter* and then inside the *filter(RequestContext requestContext)* method insert a check that verifies that the TLS connection adhere's to your requirement.

```
if("TLSv1.2".equals(requestContext.getProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.net.secure_protocol_version"))
{
   throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid TLS version");
}
```

This example is from Tomcat 8, but I suspect an option may be available for other containers.